# How do I validate JSON in Perl?

Tags: json, perl

I am familiar with the `decode_json()` function which attempts to decode a JSON string, and terminates the Perl program with error if it fails to do so—but this question is *not* about that function.

What I want to do is this—I want a function through which I can run a JSON string and the function will simply tell me whether or not the JSON string is kosher—and if it *isn't* kosher, give me *detailed* information what is wrong with it.

Is there a function like this? If so, can someone here just point me in the right direction?

The function does *not* need to decode the JSON string—it just needs to inform the calling program if the JSON string *can* be decoded—and allow the calling program to continue it's run regardless of the outcome.

If something *is* wrong with the string - I need to know more than just what *kind* of error it is, but *where* in the string that error is—including what line number if the string is to be interpreted as the full-contents of a file. In short, information that is useful for debugging the JSON file that the string was read from.

Comment: What is [PERL](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f)?

Answer (score 9):

`decode_json()` croaks on error.  You can catch that error by wrapping in an `eval` or using Try::Tiny, if you need to use the data programmatically.  The croak error message shows where the json parser failed.

> $perl_scalar = decode_json $json_text
>
> The opposite of encode_json: expects an UTF-8 (binary) string and tries to parse that as an UTF-8 encoded JSON text, returning the resulting reference. Croaks on error.

http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-3.01/XS.pm#FEATURES

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use JSON qw(decode_json);

my $maybe_json = '{"foo":"bar", "baz"}';  # invalid, baz key is missing value
my $json_out = eval { decode_json($maybe_json) };
if ($@)
{
    print "decode_json failed, invalid json. error:$@\n";
}
```

produces:

```
decode_json failed, invalid json. error:':' expected, at character offset 19 (before "}") at ./foo.pl line 6.
```

Deciphering the decode failure message can be frustratingly difficult.

This one is easy, because we know it is caused by a key without a value, so the parser complains that it didn't find the `:` it expected at char 19.  It also adds the useful 'before "}"' message to help the human interpret the error.

It might be nice to have a way to automatically parse the error message and show a larger chunk of the input string.

Let's take a quick python diversion, does that json parser provide a more useful error?  Nope, it just shows char 19 without even the "before }" context.

```
>>> import json
>>> maybe_json = '{"foo":"bar", "baz"}'
>>> json.loads(maybe_json)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/andrew/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/andrew/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/andrew/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting : delimiter: line 1 column 20 (char 19)
```

So, what's the final answer?  The json parser specification is pretty simple and in case of error just quits.  Call the parser, if it succeeds the string was valid, else show the user where it died and ask what to do.  Perl's json parser also allows options for a more relaxed translation, like interpreting single quotes (illegal) as double quotes (valid).  See `relaxed` and `allow_singlequote` options.

Maybe you do want a linter?

Comment: I wrapped the statement in eval{}. The execution of the program did not terminate -- but aside from this, nothing was achieved, and this alone isn't helpful. The calling program does not receive any diagnostic information - and the trudging-on of the program comes at the expense that the error message which previously was seen by the user (which wasn't nearly enough to be useful - but was at least something) gets forwarded directly to the bit-bucket instead. I am no closer to knowing where in a large JSON file an obscure error might reside.

Comment: Sophia_ES : what text is in the error message?  Does it provide information about the failed json?  Do you have an example broken json file?

Answer (score 1):

This is called “linting”.  There is a very good JavaScript Linter package on CPAN: [`JavaScript::JSLint`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JavaScript::JSLint)

From the documentation;

```
use JavaScript::JSLint;

my @errors = jslint($javascript);
for my $err (@errors) {
    print "$err->{reason} at line $err->{line}\n";
}
```

Comment: A Javascript linter isn't going to give you any useful information about a chunk of JSON. Except that the JSON might be valid Javascript.

Comment: @friedo have to disagree, it gives quite detailed information, paste the sample json from http://json.org/example to http://www.jslint.com/ and have a look. The linter will identify unclosed strings, parens, etc. Bad names, variables, and more.

Comment: and it will tell you nothing about whether the string is valid JSON at all.

Comment: JSON doesn't have parens or variables…

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I am barking up the wrong tree trying to do this in PERL. Maybe I should seek a command-line utility that will read in a JSON file and output the diagnostic in an easy-to-parse format --- so that I can call that command-line utility *from* PERL?

Comment: By the way - in reference to my previous comment about looking for a command-line utility --- should I ask if anyone here can point me to one, or would that be a subject for a separate question?

Answer (score 1):

6 years later....

This might have been the answer you are looking for:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::JSON

It tests to see if a given json string is valid json. If not... you could use the jslinter options that others have suggested here to get reasons why not, but otherwise you could move ahead safely.

Best of luck